# When I make changes to the security settings in FrontOffice, those changes don't go to BackOffice

Tags: security

When I look at the authorization requests, I notice that the security settings remain the same as what they were before I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why the problem occurs, but restart your IIS or rebuild the project in Visual Studio and the security settings should then show up in Back Office.